# Was there a major shift in the civil war in Libya in the last twelve months?

Tags: government, libya

[This 1 year old BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-19744533) says the following map shows who controls what in Libya:

[image]

But [this map](http://libya.liveuamap.com/en/2016/17-december-today-is-theoretically-the-expiration-date-of) shows the opposite:

[image]

Was there a major shift in the civil war in Libya in the last twelve months?

Comment: From what I read in the press, it was not a military shift but a political one. In both the Tripoli based and Tobruk based gouvernement there are factions in favor and against joining with the other gouvernement. This generated a pretty original situation when the leader of the tobruk gouvernement arrived in Tripoli with UN support and managed to reach some kind of agreement. He lost the approval of his gouvernement later though. Hence the shift of the UN backing. Note that the lines separating the two are quite similar.

Comment: On a side note, having maps describing the same groups would help. The second one makes less distinctions than the first. Maybe they have a reason for it  (new alliances for instance ) but it doesn't show this information